# Проблемы с кэшем в эмуляторе Андроид Студио при работе с SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Изучаю работу с SQLite при создании андроид-приложений, делая небольшую задачку по разработке теста (quiz). Этот тест хранит вопросы и ответы в базе данных, я делаю его на основе видеоролика одного немца - если нужно, дам ссылку на канал/код.

Так вот, в коде метода, который заполняет базу данных вопросами, допустил ошибку - при копировании первой строки по невнимательности не изменил её, и вместо

```
    private void fillQuestionsTable() {
    Question q1 = new Question("A is correct", "A", "B", "C", 1);
    addQuestion(q1);
    Question q2 = new Question("B is correct", "A", "B", "C", 2);
    addQuestion(q2);
    Question q3 = new Question("C is correct", "A", "B", "C", 3);
    addQuestion(q3);
    Question q4 = new Question("A is correct again", "A", "B", "C", 1);
    addQuestion(q4);
    Question q5 = new Question("B is correct again", "A", "B", "C", 2);
    addQuestion(q5);
}
```

у меня было

```
    private void fillQuestionsTable() {
    Question q1 = new Question("A is correct", "A", "B", "C", 1);
    addQuestion(q1);
    Question q1 = new Question("A is correct", "A", "B", "C", 1);
    addQuestion(q1);
    Question q1 = new Question("A is correct", "A", "B", "C", 1);
    addQuestion(q1);
    Question q1 = new Question("A is correct", "A", "B", "C", 1);
    addQuestion(q1);
    Question q1 = new Question("A is correct", "A", "B", "C", 1);
    addQuestion(q1);

}
```

Соответственно, в БД все так и записалось.

Я сразу же исправил эту ошибку, после того, как нашел её, однако при запуске эмулятора (обычно я работаю с устройством Nexus 5X API 26 x86) ничего не изменилось - каждый раз выводился все тот же первый вопрос.

Проверил, что в БД заносятся уже разные вопросы с помощью DB browser for SQLite - действительно, в таблице БД были уже разные вопросы, а не первый, повторяющийся пять раз, как в самом начале.

В итоге додумался запустить другое устройство на эмуляторе (Nexus 5 API 26) - и все заработало. Получается, что у первого устройства данные, передаваемые первый раз в БД, были закэшированы.

Как-то можно удалить кэш только для этого устройства в эмуляторе или проще будет удалить Nexus 5X API 26 x86, а затем установить его заново?

Comment: Проблема не связана с эмулятором, на реальном устройстве будет тоже самое. Можно просто удалить тестируемое приложение с устройства, с ним удалится и созданная база. Вообще проблема странная (если в БД записи изменились, то и в приложении они должны меняться тоже) и для ответа, почему так происходит информации недостаточно. По разработке викторины могу порекомендовать почитать книги П.Дейтел "Android для разработчиков" и Б.Филлипс "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" там подробно и на русском разбирается создание  эти игры

Comment: Установил в эмуляторе копию Nexus 5X API 26 x86 - все отлично теперь на ней запускается и работает... Поэтому думаю, что все-таки что-то кэшируется в конкретном устройстве в эмуляторе.

Comment: намного больше вероятность того, что с вашим кодом что то было не так, чем необъяснимое кэширование лишь на некоторых эмуляторах. Эмулятор вообще не копия какого то устройства и названия  в них служат только чтобы отличить один от другого. Разница в эмуляторах заключается только в эмулируемых характеристиках, как объем памяти, размер экрана, версия API и тп. - отдельные их экземпляры не обладают какими то уникальными свойствами реальных устройств, помимо указанных в  настройках параметров эмуляции. Вы можете отредактировать существующее вирт. устройство и будет у вас Nexus 5 с 128мб оперативки